# Can I say "We could arrange something till there"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Can I say "till there" to refer an specific time in the future? For example, I said that I would be free in August and I would like to add that we could arrange something for August. So, can I say "We could arrange something till there."?

Comment: "There" would be understood as a translation error for *then*.

Comment: @FernandaCosta An easy way to remember this: **there** is similar to **here**, both refer to a place/location.  **Then** is similar to **when**, both are used to speak about time.

Comment: This question should be left open as it is a mistranslation into English. But could happen to others, too.

Answer (score 2):

No, neither *till* nor *there* works.

It is very rare to use *there* for a point in time, as opposed to *then* - I hesitate to say we *never* do it, but I can't think of any examples.

And if you used *till then* here, that would most likely be understood as "We can arrange something to cover the time between now and then".

I think what you mean is either

> We can arrange something then.

(Meaning that when I am free, in August, we can make an arrangement), or

> We can arrange something for then.

(Meaning that at some unspecified time - maybe now - we can make an arrangement for August).

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Colin, this is a mistranslation from Portuguese of the word até where the meaning is **by** then. Of course, I didn't expect you to know that...

Comment: Lambie: I didn't know that, but it doesn't surprise me at all. I was once using a technical spec. written by a French group, which talked about something being read into a certain buffer. I eventually worked out that they meant it was being read _from_ that buffer. I guess (though I don't know for sure) that the writer had been taught that _en_ corresponded to _into_.

Comment: Yes, Colin, not surprising re the French. Because in French *de* can mean *from* and *of*. I see that mistranslated a lot from French. Anyway, I only hope Fernanda acknowledges this. I do happen to speak Portuguese (and French) fluently which is why I "caught" it. The funny thing is that *by* as in "I can do this by June, in French is: d'ici le juin. where the ici refers to now or today's date.

Answer (score 0):

Question: Can I say "till there" to refer an specific time in the future? For example, I said that I would be free in August and I would like to add that we could arrange something for August. So, can I say "We could arrange something till there."?

Answer:
In Portuguese, you use **até** [until or till, the second is informal] there.

In English, we say by.

"We could arrange something **by August**" OR "by then".

**até agosto**
**até aquele mês**
**até lá**